# Angular ui grid - specific class for unselectable row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use angular ui-grid to display my data.

I enabled the option to select row in gridOptions:

`enableRowSelection: true,`

But for specific rows I disable the selection by this code:

```
$scope.mygrid.isRowSelectable = function (row) {
    if (row.entity.id == 2) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This is work, I cant select row with id =2,

But I want to add class for this row to notify that it is unselectable.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Highlight the actual row:**

You can write your own rowTemplate and assign the class to the row based on the entity id something like this,

```
 var rowTemplate =  '<div>' +
                 '  <div ng-class="{ \'red\': row.entity.company==\'Enersol\' }" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
                 '</div>';
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    rowTemplate:rowTemplate,
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name'},
      { field: 'company'}
    ]
  };
```

Instead of the row.entity.company=\'Enersol\' you can change it to row.entity.id and assign the class name.

In this example the the 'red' gives background color of yellow and foreground color of red.

Take a look at this plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/vaqBY235Lfz7WLvy0FCc?p=preview

**To modify the actual row header icons:**

You can override the template for the selection row header buttons and add custom class css. Inject templateCache in your controller and override the template like this.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected , 'ui-grid-icon-cancel':!grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity), 'ui-grid-icon-ok':grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity)}\" ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
  );
```

The template uses a method in your controller scope to identify whether the row is selectable.

Sample plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/vaqBY235Lfz7WLvy0FCc?p=preview

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear, but I want the specfifc class just for the check column(the column in the side of row, which I can click on it to select the row), and not for all row

Comment: @BrMe yea that wasn't clear from your question. You can assign a function to the `cellClass` property and return the class you want dynamically. See more here: http://brianhann.com/customize-ui-grid-with-dynamic-cell-classes/

Comment: @BrMe Ok, looks like you are trying to customize the row selection header with the tick mark. The template for the selectionRow is selectionRowHeader and you will have to override that to change it to a different symbol is the row is not selectable. i will try to get you a simple example on it.

Comment: @Kathir Yea, That exactly what I need. I want to show the select column of  unselected row in red color, to indicate user that he can't select this row. I would love to get an examle code,

Comment: @BrMe I have updated the answer with the row header icon update.

Answer (score 0):

In the columnDefs you can add a [cellClass](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/111_cellClass).

```
function applyClass(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (row.entity.IsMapped) {
        return 'disabledRow';
    }
}

$scope.yourGrid = {
    columnDefs: [
        { cellClass: applyClass }
    ]
};
```